# How Store a Cookie of a Hashed Password in Tornado?

Tags: cookies, hash, tornado

So I'm working on a login system in Tornado. I originally tried using websockets (doesn't work) and switched to a regular web server. I'm trying to set a cookie so that I can remember if someone's logged in on the websocket. The problem that's coming up is a

> ValuError: Invalid cookie

I looked up the Tornado source code (http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.0/_modules/tornado/web.html), and this is caused by matching a regular expression for any characters in between 0x00 and 0x20

```
if re.search(r"[\x00-\x20]", name + value):
    # Don't let us accidentally inject bad stuff
    raise ValueError("Invalid cookie %r: %r" % (name, value))
```

The thing is, I'm always going to have these characters, because the Hash generates random bytes. Is there any way I can get around this?

Answer (score 1):

That check actually isn't strict enough; there are a lot of restrictions on what can go in a cookie.  In general if you want to put arbitrary binary data in a cookie you'll have to encode it (e.g. in base64).  If you use tornado's secure_cookie functions they'll base64 encode the data for you.

Also note that it's not a good idea to store password hashes in a cookie - the best practice is to generate a random session id that is stored somewhere on the server side and put that in the cookie.